# Problems building a cloned project using GIT for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I started a new solution and created three sub-projects:

1. Domain (Class Library)
2. Web (ASP.Net MVC 4)
3. Unit Test Project

After that, I just pushed my files to GitHub repository using GIT for Visual Studio 2012 update 2.

The files are pushed just fine (bin folder is not pushed).

I went to my other computer and cloned the repository successfully.

I tried to Build the project and got the following error messages:

```
Error   15  The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) D:\Source\Repos\[Project Folder]\MyApp.Web\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs    2   18  MyApp.Web
Error   16  The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) D:\Source\Repos\[Project Folder]\MyApp.Web\Global.asax.cs   7   18  MyApp.Web
Error   17  The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\Source\Repos\[Project Folder]\MyApp.Web\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs    9   44  MyApp.Web
```

Please notice that these are totally new and blank projects and they build with no problem at the first computer. all the errors displayed here were in Web project as it is the startup project of the solution.

I am assuming that some files are mandatory in the Bin folder (which is not pushed from my first pc).

Any idea how to solve this problem as we are getting more employees involved in the project and will need them just to clone the repo to have everything working for them just fine!

Regards

Comment: Did you commit packages folder in the solution folder to your repository?

Comment: No, I didn't. Can I do that from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either enable [NuGet package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) or commit binaries from installed packages in your solution.